# Token-Pasting Operator pasting "Func_foo" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c++, macros

I am using `##` (Token-Pasting Operator) to form a function call.

According to my understanding, a simple example may look like this.

```
#include <iostream>

#define CALL(x) Func_##x##()

void Func_foo() { std::cout << "Hi from foo()." << std::endl; }

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  CALL(foo);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code with `g++ -std=c++14 -O3 test.cc`. The G++ version is 7.3.1.
It returns the following error.

```
error: pasting "Func_foo" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

If I change the macro to `#define CALL(x) Func_##x()` (delete the second `##`), the error will be solved.

Why the second `##` is redundant? The `##` connects strings and substitutes with macro arguments if possible. For example, I change the function name to `Func_foo1()`, then the macro should be `#define CALL(x) Func_##x##1()`. This works as my expected.

I am a little confused about the macro definition `#define CALL(x) Func_##x()`.

Comment: `## ` concatenates 2 strings. So you need only 1 between `Func_` and `foo` (in this example). In your 2nd case you need another `##` to concatenate the `1` suffix.

Comment: *The ## connects strings* - you answered yourself. `(` is a separate token from function name, concatenating them into one token results in an invalid token (since identifiers cannot contain `(` character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **token** is the smallest element of a C++ program that is meaningful to the compiler.

The `##` Token-pasting operator does *not* concatenate arbitrary printable characters.  It concatenates two tokens **into one token**.

> Why the second ## is redundant?

Because concatenating `Func_foo` and `()` does not produce a single token.

Comment: My confusion is why the macro `Func_##x()` does not failed to do substitution for connecting `Func_` and `x()`.

Comment: The `##` in `Func_##x()` connects `Func_` and `x`.  The `()` characters are not involved in the token-pasting.  They are separate tokens.

Comment: The `(` is a separate token. So for macro `Func_##x()`, the `##` recognizes the string behind it ended when meeting a `(`. The macro can connect `Func_` and `x`, instead of recognizing the string behind it as `x()`. Is there some other characters wok like `(`, except `)`?